# Apache RewriteRule for each User directory

Tags: apache-2.4, mod-rewrite, suexec, mod-userdir

I have two directories in each of my users' home folders: `.html-data` and `.cgi-bin`. The first one contains static (.html) files, the second one contains files for dynamic document generation.

Each user should be able to publish the content of the `.html-data` folder on `http://myhost.com/~<username>/` and the content of the `.cgi-bin` folder on `http://myhost.com/~<username>/cgi-bin/`. The scripts for dynamic content creation should be **executed as the user who provides them** (e.g. `~steve/cgi-bin/test.cgi` should be executed as user steve).

For that I configured the following configuration for the userdir module of Apache 2.4:

```
UserDir .html-data
UserDir disabled root

<Directory "/home/*/.html-data">
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /~username/
    RewriteRule "^/cgi-bin/(.*)" "../../.cgi-bin/$1"
    AllowOverride FileInfo AuthConfig Limit Indexes
    Options MultiViews Indexes SymLinksIfOwnerMatch IncludesNoExec
    Require method GET POST OPTIONS
</Directory>

<Directory "/home/*/.cgi-bin">
    Options ExecCGI
    SetHandler cgi-script
    Satisfy any
</Directory>
```

However, this does not work. The RewriteRule seems wrong. **How can I refer to the user's `.cgi-bin` directory?**

This is the error log:

```
[Thu Aug 04 20:14:17 2016] [trace3] mod_rewrite.c(477): [client 10.0.2.2:44058] 10.0.2.2 - - [myhost.com/sid#19f4a48][rid#1a639b0/initial] [perdir /home/*/.html-data/] add path info postfix: /home/steve/.html-data/cgi-bin -> /home/steve/.html-data/cgi-bin/hello.cgi
[Thu Aug 04 20:14:17 2016] [trace3] mod_rewrite.c(477): [client 10.0.2.2:44058] 10.0.2.2 - - [myhost.com/sid#19f4a48][rid#1a639b0/initial] [perdir /home/*/.html-data/] applying pattern '^/cgi-bin/(.*)' to uri '/home/steve/.html-data/cgi-bin/hello.cgi'
[Thu Aug 04 20:14:17 2016] [trace1] mod_rewrite.c(477): [client 10.0.2.2:44058] 10.0.2.2 - - [myhost.com/sid#19f4a48][rid#1a639b0/initial] [perdir /home/*/.html-data/] pass through /home/steve/.html-data/cgi-bin
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. I am using [mpm_itk](http://mpm-itk.sesse.net/) now. Combined with rewrite rules, one can define the user executing the scripts:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule "^.*" - [E=ITKUID:http]
RewriteRule "^/~root.*" - [L,R=404]
RewriteRule "^/~([a-z]+)/cgi-bin(.*)" "/home/$1/.cgi-bin$2" [L,E=ITKUID:$1]
RewriteRule "^/~([a-z]+)/?(.*)" "/home/$1/.html-data/$2" [L,E=ITKUID:http]
AssignUserIDExpr %{reqenv:ITKUID}
```